# is it possible to get php results over to a html and still leave php code on server side

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have rewritten my webpage a few times already in hopes of speeding it up.  what I have is a hosted website that collects data from an xml and displays it back to the html page.  I used .js at first but the page updates the data each time the page is accessed as it is slow--almost 15 seconds to build scoring page.  I tried using runat ="server" but it wouldn't work.  my webhost is dreamhost and they are unix based.  so I decided to try my hand at .php.  I am able to get all the data using .php but now I don't know how to display the results back to my html page.  using java I would just do : home1 is a variable returned from a .js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("home1").innerHTML= home1;
</script>
```

and just attached the .js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gettourneyname.js"></script>
```

My question is how can I get the .php variables over?  I am lost at this point.

Comment: Are you saying that the server side (PHP) is generating HTML content that you want to assign to the id="home1" element?

Comment: yes--I just don't know how to do it--it took too long using javascript

Comment: You probably want to use AJAX to fetch the HTML content from your php file, and assign it to your HTML element. See my answer below.

Comment: Just to clarify the code I posted is the js code I used before. What I am looking for is a way to use php to et the results.

Comment: js codes runs on the front-end. It will not run on the back-end (php). you'll have to convert your js code to php. Then my answer below will work. What do you mean when you say "I am able to get all the data using .php?"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following jquery code. The code below would live in your HTML page, and it would call your php file. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ for more info.

```
$.get( "pathToYourPHP", function( data ) {
 $( "#home1" ).html( data );
});
```